# Selenium - Opera webdriver - switch between frames

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to switch between frames the same way i did with IE,SA,CH,FF webdrivers,
but while i'm trying with opera:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("something"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

it fails at `driver.switchTo().frame(frame)`, and the resulted exception is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Invalid frame index 4
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c187d01409a5dc3b7f8251859150c8af0bcb', time: '2013-04-09 10:39:28'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_10'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

hope for answers,
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think that for first measure, try to download the latest version of Selenium [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

The latest version is 2.39 while you are using 2.32

A lot of fixes done since 2.32, some of them relate to Opera browser.

Answer (score 0):

i tried it and i got this one:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Invalid frame index 4
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'demosaar', ip: '192.0.16.63', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86',           
os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_10'    
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this, hope it would help:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html